# Error [SDF.cc:722] Unable to find value for key

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using ROS with the hector gazebo quadrotor package. Whenever I spawn my quadrotor I get this error:

```
Error [SDF.cc:722] Unable to find value for key[samples]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to where this error might be coming from? This error appears to not be causing any problems, but it is filling my screen.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/38/error-%5Bsdf.cc:722%5D-unable-to-find-value-for-key/) by [Sameer Parekh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/33/sameer-parekh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This output happens when some code tries to get data that doesn't exist.

So, somewhere code like the following is being executed:

```
sdf->GetValue...("samples");
```

You could find the answer by setting a breakpoint at SDF.cc:722, and then run a backtrace.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0